# "KeyUp" event for Pyqt4

Tags: qt, python-2.7, pyqt, qt4, pyqt4

I am making a piano application in Python 2.7 using Pyqt4 and I want my keys to change color when I press a key (this is working with `keyPressEvent` in my app), then I want my key to change to the original color. I think I need a "KeyUp" event for that.

Does such an event exist in Pyqt4?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct term is "key release", not "key up". In pyqt4 you would have to use [`keyReleaseEvent`](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qwidget.html#keyReleaseEvent).